# 'Illegal parameter number' error using underbrace in QCircuit environment

Tags: errors, braces, circuits

Using QCircuit, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}

\Qcircuit @C=0.5cm @R=.2cm {
\lstick{\ket{0}_n} & \gate{H_n} & \qw & \hdots && \gate{\mathsf{M}} & \rstick{\ket{y}_n} \qw \\
& & & \underbrace{}_{\text{some text}}
}

\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

which is exactly what I want. However, I get the following error when compiling my source files:

`Illegal parameter number in definition of \lastprentry@@ }`

Why is this error showing up and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find mysterious error messages, a good strategy is trying with `\protect`:

```
\Qcircuit @C=0.5cm @R=.2cm {
\lstick{\ket{0}_n} & \gate{H_n} & \qw & \hdots && \gate{\mathsf{M}} & \rstick{\ket{y}_n} \qw \\
& & & \protect\underbrace{}_{\text{some text}}
}
```

However, this is a common problem with Xy-pic if an entry starts with “risky” tokens and `\relax` works: it stops expanding the first token in the cell, which is the problem in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}

\Qcircuit @C=0.5cm @R=.2cm {
\lstick{\ket{0}_n} & \gate{H_n} & \qw & \hdots && \gate{\mathsf{M}} & \rstick{\ket{y}_n} \qw \\
& & & \relax\underbrace{}_{\text{some text}}
}

\end{document}
```

Also bracing the item will do:

```
\Qcircuit @C=0.5cm @R=.2cm {
\lstick{\ket{0}_n} & \gate{H_n} & \qw & \hdots && \gate{\mathsf{M}} & \rstick{\ket{y}_n} \qw \\
& & & {\underbrace{}_{\text{some text}}}
}
```

[image]